# Why does the messenger app don't open chat head?

Tags: applications, facebook, facebook-messenger

I am facing this problem in my device Redmi note 3. It says in notification bar that chat head is active but actually there is nothing on the screen.Please help.

Comment: Troubleshooting the app by clearing all data and cache might solve the problem. Also update the app.

Comment: If @MANI solutions do not work, try ensuring the app is allowed to use notifications. It uses a persistent one to keep the bubbles on top.